# Proper way to wait for a second page to load with Capybara when the first has the same field as the second

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec2

I'm having a problem with a spec that visits two forms with the same field ("Email") on both forms. If I don't manually sleep, Capybara seems to be finding the "Email" field from the first visit in the second portion of the test.

```
# visit the first form and fill out a subscription
visit new_front_form_subscription_path(@web_form_1.id)
fill_in "Email", with: "subscriber@example.com"
fill_in "Field 1", with: "my first data"
click_button "Subscribe"

# visit the second form and fill out a subscription
visit new_front_form_subscription_path(@web_form_2.id)
sleep 1
fill_in "Email", with: "subscriber@example.com"
fill_in "Field 2", with: "my second data"
click_button "Subscribe"
```

With the sleep in there, the spec passes with flying colors. Without the sleep, the second form submission gets a validation error -- blaming a blank "Email" value.

Is there a proper way to handle this? I dislike introducing manual sleeps into the specs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways using which you can solve it:

1. Use another locator that is present only at the second page to select "Email" field:

   ```
   find('#second_page #email').set('subscriber@example.com')
   ```
2. Write a statement that will wait for a second page to be loaded instead of sleep:

   ```
   visit new_front_form_subscription_path(@web_form_2.id)
   expect(page).to have_css('locator_present_only_at_second_page')
   fill_in "Email", with: "subscriber@example.com"
   ```

Comment: This is a little bit kludgey but probably the best way to do it. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but wouldn't it be possible that the `expect` line fails if the second page hasn't loaded yet?

Comment: @aceofbassgreg Almost all capybara methods wait automatically (including rspec matchers) - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends

Comment: Cool! Spurred me on to reading:  http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara

Answer (score 7):

The above answers are correct, but difficult to implement if you have a large test suite, because you have to find a unique element on each page.  If you are a graduate from the Michael Hartl school of rails there is an easy way to solve this.  Hartl teaches setting a different `@title` instance variable for every controller action. This is then used in application.html.erb to set an html title element for every page.

I certainly do, and it allowed a very easy  way to fix up all my flaky tests that failed because the page had not loaded properly.  You cannot find the title tag because it is not visible. So what I did was put at the bottom of the application.html.erb, the following code;

```
<%= content_tag :div, "[#{title}]", class: 'rspec_eyes_only' if Rails.env.test? %>
```

This inserts, if you are in test mode, a div with title text, surrounded by square brackets. Then I wrote a helper that goes in rails_helper.rb

```
def wait_for_page_load(title)
  find('div.rspec_eyes_only', text: title)
end
```

I already has another helper to test for the correct title, so I modified it to add in `wait_for_page_load` i.e;

```
def title_is_correct(title)
  full_title = "#{BaseTitle} | #{title}"
  wait_for_page_load "[#{full_title}]"
  expect(page.title).to eq full_title
end
```

These simple changes cleared up almost all of my flaky tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you resorted to Andrey's 2) above, you might want to check out the [holdon gem](https://github.com/briandamaged/holdon), which will allow you to write a block that will wait for an element to load, then move to the `fill_in` method once that element loads.

Comment: Equivalent for `e = HoldOn.until(timeout: 60, interval: 5) { s.first(:css, "div#bastard") }` is `e = find('div#bastard', wait: 60, match: :first)`. Holdon gem is completely unnecessary. But I prefer not to pass `:match` param: `find('div#bastard', wait: 60)`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it can be done this way. For example to click on buttons which are found after a modal pop-up (or another page) is loaded, add the following block to your macro file.

```
def wait_until_modal
   page.has_css?('.modal')
end
```

Here class .modal is found on the on the pop-up page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `, wait: 10` to the first line following the new page load:

```
visit new_front_form_subscription_path(@web_form_2.id)
fill_in "Email", with: "subscriber@example.com", wait: 10 # <--
```

I just had a similar situation:

```
visit promo_path
fill_in 'promo_code', with: 'HALFPRICEPROMO'
click_button 'Activate' # onClick does things and eventually loads the next page
assert page.has_content? 'Confirm your email address', wait: 10 # <--
```

Any and all assertions fail without the `wait` above. I put `10` to play it extra safe; `3` seems to be the minimum for my situation.

I found the answer here: [Make capybara wait until Ajax finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072556/make-capybara-wait-until-ajax-finishes)

Answer (score 0):

With SitePrism you can use `wait_until_true` to test the `current_url`.

```
new_path = new_front_form_subscription_path(@web_form_2.id)
visit new_path
wait_until_true { current_url.include? new_path }
fill_in "Email", with: "subscriber@example.com"
fill_in "Field 2", with: "my second data"
click_button "Subscribe"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the **"timestamping"** approach. Change your layout file (e.g.`application.html.haml`) to serve the timestamp:

```
%body{"data-rendered-at" => Time.now.to_f.to_s}
```

Then create a helper method to wait the page unloading:

```rb
# in capybara_helper.rb
def with_waiting_unload(&block)
  current_rendered_at = find('body')['data-rendered-at']
  yield
  expect(page).not_to have_css("body[data-rendered-at='#{current_rendered_at}']")
end
```

Finally your code will be:

```rb
# (snip)...
with_waiting_unload do
    visit new_front_form_subscription_path(@web_form_2.id)
end
sleep 1
fill_in "Email", with: "subscriber@example.com"
# ...(snip)
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this for page transitions:

```rb
visit page1

do_something

visit page2

Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
  sleep(0.1) until current_url.include?(page2)
end

do_something_else
```